# Mapserver - label at beginning of line string (WMS)

Tags: wms, mapserver, linestring

I am creating a WMS service made up of linestrings pulled from a POSTGIS database

I want to label the start of each line with a sequence number. At present I can label the centre of each with:-

```
 PROCESSING 'LABEL_NO_CLIP=1'  (to prevent repetition across tiles)
 ....
 LABEL
      COLOR 132 31 31
      TYPE TRUETYPE
      FONT "arialbd"
      SIZE 12
      POSITION AUTO
 END
```

This places the label in the middle of the line string. Any idea how to place it at the start?

Note that GEOMTRANSFORM "start" does not work with labels

Comment: sorry for saying this but I'd like to ask you a bit more of clarification to see if I can be of help here, do you need only the label at the end of each linestring? no matter what if it's the upper or lower end?

Comment: I need a single label at the start of the linestring

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, there is no way to do that directly with mapserver. I have not tested this, but given you are using postgis you can probably get something close to what you want by creating a POINT layer and a specially crafted postgis query to extract the first point of each linestring. This would be something like:

```
layer
 type point
 name "line_start_labels"
 connectiontype postgis
 connection "blabla"
 data "start_point from (select ST_StartPoint(the_geom) as start_point, id, label_column from mytable) as foo using unique id using srid=XXXX"
 labelitem "label_column"
 class
  label
   #color, font, size, etc...
  end
 end
end
```

Note that in this case your label will not be oriented along the linestring, and that you will have to render the actual linestrings in a separate layer. You might be able to compute the angle to orient your label inside the postgis query, and bind that for mapserver:

```
data "start_point from ( select ...,
        -- some postgis/sql code to compute an angle in [0..360] from the first and second point -- as            orientation,
        ) as foo ...."
....
class
 label
  ...
  angle [orientation]
 end
end
```

Comment: Been there too, had to add : 
degrees(ST_Azimuth(ST_StartPoint(the_geom), ST_EndPoint(the_geom))) as orientation
to be more specific about "some postgis code to compute an angle when you have 2 points vertices as Lines.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
LAYER
    LABELMAXSCALEDENOM      433344
    TOLERANCE               10
    TOLERANCEUNITS          pixels

            LABEL
                    BUFFER          10
                    SIZE            15
                    ANGLE           FOLLOW
                    POSITION        AUTO
                    MINFEATURESIZE  10
                    PRIORITY        10
                    PARTIALS        FALSE
                    FORCE           TRUE
                    ANTIALIAS       TRUE
            END

END
```

This has two properties:

1. it allows me to have the label on the line (it fits to the feature,
   ie. line or point).
2. it depends on a maximum scale, so labels don't
       get agglomerated after some specific zoom in/out.

At the end, with this I can move freely in my map and labels move at my pace, ie., if I follow one linestring the label will keep appearing once I move through the map. If you just need all labels no matter what scale you use, just get rid off of the LABELMAXSCALEDENOM property.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I am not sure that will achieve what I am after. For me it is important that the start of the linestring is labelled. I don't care about any other portion of the line.